# Git : creating new branch from another branch (should reflect in corresponding repository)

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I have one branch called `x` and i want to create a new branch called `y` with the current existing code from `x` branch with out commit history. It is not for development so creating a local branch which will not reflect in github won't help. So I would like to create a brand new branch `y` from the existing branch `x` which will not have the commits of `x` branch so that it will be helpful to share the `y` **github** link with others

I have used **create new branch**, **create new branch from** in **VS Code** but that was not reflecting in my repository

So please mention the steps to do the above process through **VS code / git command**

Comment: Sounds like you want a tag, actually, not a branch.

Comment: I'm not that much aware of tags so thought to create a new branch, I will look on tags